# load socket.io with Angular 2 AOT

Tags: angularjs, sockets, angular2-aot, rollupjs

I've created a project in angular2 with socket.io to emit / listen socket communication. Everything works fine in JIT ( or npm start) but when I try to compile the code via rollup to lunch it as AOT for production usage It don't work.

Node version : 6.9.4
npm version : 3.10.6

typings.json

```
    {
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#7.0.0+20170110233017",
    "socket.io-client": "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20161116080703"
  },
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#138ad74b9e8e6c08af7633964962835add4c91e2",
    "socket-io-client": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
map : {"socket.io-client": 'npm:socket.io-client'}
packages : { "socket.io-client": {
            main: './socket.io.js',
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        } }
```

package.json : 
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2"

mycomponent.ts

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
var url = 'http://localhost:4500';
export var socket = io(url);
```

"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json executes successfully but 
"node_modules/.bin/rollup" -c rollup-config.js gives error : `cannot call a namespace ('io')`

If i change my component import line and set `import io from socket.io-client` then i get error `module 'socket.io-client' has no default export`

I would appreciate if someone can guide me through as this is my second day of troubleshooting and trying as per other forums.

Thanks in Advance,
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

Keep import:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

And add plugin to rollup.js:

```
{
    name: 'replace io imports',
    transform: code => ({
        code: code.replace(/import\s*\*\s*as\s*io/g, 'import io'),
        map: { mappings: '' }
    })
},
```